# How to command python to continue beyond the loop?

Tags: python, loops

```
 pos = [10, 100, 1000]
    cigar = [[(0, 150), (3, 50), (0, 130), (3, 270), (0, 750),(2,50),(1, 70), (0,500)], [(0, 250), (3, 250), (0, 160), (3, 270), (0, 750) ,(0,300)], [(0, 150), (3, 150), (0, 130), (3, 250), (0, 950)]] 
   def find (cigar, pos):
        matches=list()
        result=list()
        #name=list()
        for i in cigar:
                if i[0] == 1:
                        continue
                end =  pos + i[1]
        #print i[1]
                item = [i[0], pos, end]
                result.append(item)
                pos=end
        for i in result:
                if i[0] < 1:
                        matches.append([i[1],i[2]]

        return matches

    for x, y in zip(cigar, pos):
        #print x, y
        res = find(x, y)
        print res
```

I have this code which gives me half of my desired output:

```
[[10, 160], [210, 340], [610, 1360], [1410, 1910]]
[[100, 350], [600, 760], [1030, 1780], [1780, 2080]]
[[1000, 1150], [1300, 1430], [1680, 2630]]
```

My desired output is:

```
[[10,160],[210,340],[610,1910]]
[[100,350],[600-760],[1030-2180]]
[[1000,1150], [1300-1430], [1680-2630]]
```

From the code:

```
for i in result:
        if i[0] < 1:
            matches.append([i[1], i[2]])    
    return matches
```

I want the appending to break every time it hits i[0] == 3. But at the end of the list if it does not find i[3] I want it to continue appending.
How can I give that command to the program?

Comment: Based on a cursory look, it sounds like the yield keyword would be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do

Comment: Thank you. I tried using it. Does not give me the output though. Gives me: 
<generator object find at 0x273ba50>

Comment: That is the expected behavior. You need to make use of the generator object as described in the linked question. You can't just change yield to return have it work.

Comment: I am very new to python. I am not able to understand how do I do it.